How Durga Puja related with Tantra shastra? Someone told me that it is mentioned in Purans
Durga Puja and it's relation with tantra shastra. Kindly explain with reference.

Tripura rahasya mahatma khanda has reference of Durga Puja. You can check the reference by Anu. It says explicitly about idol iconography with clay and all.

There may be other references. I am not sure Tripura Rahasya is tantric text.
